# Styling anchor tags without href's--being used to trigger Javascript within page

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, anchor

What is the most cross-browser effective way to style anchor tags without href's?

I found this [article](http://eschembor.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/css-ie6-compatibility-for-a-tags-with-no-href-attribute/) on making the styles apply in older versions of IE by throwing in an href="#". However, I am applying this about halfway down the page and find that it acts as it should; brings you to the top of the page again. This makes the page 'jump' which is a bad experience for anyone trying to use the bottom half of the page. But...when I take the href's out IE will not apply the css styles.

Thoughts?

Comment: IE will be dead pretty soon, IMO you should not even bother handling IE's edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use markup like this...

```
<a id="myLink" href="JavascriptDisabled.htm">Jump</a>
```

JavascriptDisabled.htm should be a page that says **Javascript must be enabled for this to work!**

Then you can override the default click functionality of the link with unobtrusive Javascript like this...

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
    //Execute your Javascript
    return false; // This prevents the redirect
  }
}
```

So people with Javascript enabled get the correct functionality.  Those with Javascript disabled will actually get a message that tells them why it's not working.  I'd say it's a win/win!

Comment: I've always used window.onload in the body tag, but over here

http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm

it talks about separating the javascript out more into the js file. I suppose that creates cleaner code...

Comment: Yes it is called behavioral separation, and it is the thing to do these days.  It's much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use `href="javascript:void(0)"` in place of `#`.  This is the most common method to get around this problem.

The anchor still gets an `href` attribute, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Not good for accessiblity because people with Javascript enabled will still see clickable links, but they do nothing.  That's not very nice!

Comment: It's better than having a clickable link with the '#' that just scrolls you to the bottom of the document.